# The Meaning of One Tree Hill

Tags: title, one-tree-hill

One of my favourite television drama series is [One Tree Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Tree_Hill_(TV_series)), which was created by [Mark Schwahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Schwahn) and premiered successfully on The WB Television Network for 9 seasons from 2003-2012.

Given my appreciation and profound ability to recall the story, I wonder about the original meaning and origin of the series' name, being One Tree Hill.

I am aware this is the name of the town or setting for the drama, it is that I wonder if there were also any **additional reasons intended by Schwahn**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's based on a U2 song that the creator likes and the address of the high school and also justified in a line in the actual show. From an [Alloy article](http://www.alloy.com/entertainment/meaning-behind-one-tree-hill-title-630/) about the title:

> For one, **Tree Hill High's address is 1 Tree Hill**; since it's the center of all the basketball, relationship, and time capsule/school shooting/Evil Dan intrigue, it makes sense. But the title didn't really make sense to fans, or even the CW producers, until episode 1×21 “The Leaving Song.”
>
> Originally **[creator] Mark Schwahn** wanted to call the show An Unkindness of Ravens, but The CW (then The WB) didn't want to alienate fans with a show only about basketball. (Schwahn got some vindication when he had Lucas write a bestselling novel about his adolescence, titled An Unkindness of Ravens.) So Schwahn **went to a favorite [U2 song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Tree_Hill_(song)) off their album The Joshua Tree.** But after executives asked about the meaning of One Tree Hill, he inserted this line into [[episode] 1×21](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0666250/combined):
>
> *Karen (to son Lucas): **There is only one Tree Hill—and it's your home.***

Comment: Thank you! I have really appreciated learning this and hearing your response.